# Is process philosophy at odds with orthodox Christian theology?

Tags: metaphysics, theology, christianity, change, process

Process philosophy regards change, as opposed to stasis, as the basis of reality. Does this contradict orthodox Christian theology, such as Catholicism, Orthodoxy, and the various Protestant denominations, or could the former be derived from the latter or a synthesis of the two be made?

Comment: According to Thomism God is a simple and immutable object. It seems to be inconsistent with process theologians declaring that God is an omnipresent relation that changes.

Comment: "*A number of contemporary Roman Catholic theologians have begun to take the Whiteheadian-Hartshornean challenge seriously, indeed to the extent that they have felt pressed, in response, to seek and exploit implicit, latent resources within Thomas' texts in order to explicate a more adequate Thomist conception of God's interrelationship with his creatures*", [Whitney, Divine Immutability in Process Philosophy and Contemporary Thomism](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/horizons/article/divine-immutability-in-process-philosophy-and-contemporary-thomism/DE510D6451024852FEDE4EA5BFB11B4D).

Comment: "*The views of Whitehead and Hartshorne should also be distinguished from those that affirm that the divine being, by an act of self-limitation, opens itself to influence from the world. Some neo-Thomists hold this view and a group of Evangelical Christian philosophers, calling themselves “open theists,” promote similar ideas. These forms of theism were influenced by process theism, but they deny its claim that God is essentially in a give-and-take relationship with the world.*" [SEP, Process Theism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/process-theism/). So the answer is essentially yes.